# AngularFire2 - Firebase storage getDownloadURL() - How to return the url for firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I've been going through the angularfire2 documentation to retrieve a downloadURl from storage. I'm hoping I'm missing something simple here.

The documentation states:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<img [src]="profileUrl | async" />`
})
 export class AppComponent {
   profileUrl: Observable<string | null>;
   constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {
   const ref = this.storage.ref('users/davideast.jpg');
   this.profileUrl = ref.getDownloadURL();
 }
}
```

However, once I've uploaded an image I want to return the download url as a string to upload to firestore. I need the download URL for an external service.

**My function**

```
uploadImage(base64data) {

  const filePath = (`myURL/photo.jpg`);
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

  var metadata = {
    contentType: 'image',
    cacheControl: "public, max-age=31536000",
  };

  const ref = this.storage.ref(filePath);
  const task = ref.putString(base64data, 'data_url', metadata).then(() => {

    var downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL();

  })

}
```

This uploads the image perfectly fine. However, I would then like to write the download URL to firestore. When console logging my 'downloadURL' variable, I get the following:

> PromiseObservable {_isScalar: false, promise: y, scheduler: undefined}

The download is inside the promise observable. How do I just get the download URL string as my variable? Once I have that I can sort the firestore updates out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer is not relevant from Firebase 5.0 release, they removed downloadURL() from upload task.** Please refer to [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage).

The `.downloadURL()` observable emits the download URL string once the upload is completed. Then you need to subscribe to get the value.

```
uploadImage(base64data) {

  const filePath = (`myURL/photo.jpg`);
  //const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

  var metadata = {
    contentType: 'image',
    cacheControl: "public, max-age=31536000",
  };

  const ref = this.storage.ref(filePath);
  const task = ref.putString(base64data, 'data_url', metadata);
  const downloadURL = task.downloadURL();

  downloadURL.subscribe(url=>{
     if(url){
         console.log(url);
         //wirte the url to firestore
     }
  })

}
```

Hope this helps. check this blog for more [detail](https://blog.angular.io/file-uploads-come-to-angularfire-6842352b3b47)

Comment: @Hareesh downloadURL will no longer be attached with Task in recent release of AngularFireStorage.

Answer (score 9):

```
//observable to store download url
downloadURL: Observable<string>;

task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
        this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
        this.downloadURL.subscribe(url=>{this.imageUrl = url})
    })
)
```

refer :https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/observable.md

Comment: There are some changes brought recently! (I believe so..) Add *** .subscribe() ** after pipe() .... like ... .pipe(finalize(....)).subscribe();

Comment: thanks this works for me only I changed to url: any

Answer (score 5):

Nesting subscriptions is an antipattern so instead of subscribing in `finalize` you should use `last` + `switchMap` or `concat` + `defer`.

**last + switchMap**

```js
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  last(),
  switchMap(() => fileRef.getDownloadURL())
).subscribe(url => console.log('download url:', url))
```

**concat + defer**

```js
concat(
  task.snapshotChanges().pipe(ignoreElements()),
  defer(() => fileRef.getDownloadURL())
).subscribe(url => console.log('download url:', url))
```

Answer (score 3):

`.downloadURL()` doesn't works longer anymore, you need to use `.getDownloadURL()` combined with `finalize()` like so:

**.html** file

```
<input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
```

**.ts** file

```
import {
  AngularFireStorage,
  AngularFireStorageReference,
  AngularFireUploadTask
} from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.scss']
})
export class UploadComponent {
    constructor(private angularFireStorage: AngularFireStorage) {}

    public uploadFile(event: any): void {
        for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
            const file = event.target.files[i];
            const fileRef: AngularFireStorageReference = this.angularFireStorage.ref(
              file.name
            );
            const task: AngularFireUploadTask = this.angularFireStorage.upload(
              file.name,
              file
            );
            task
                .snapshotChanges()
                .pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe(downloadURL => {
                        console.log(downloadURL);
                    });
              })
          )
          .subscribe();
       }
   }
}
```

Also, note the **@angular/fire**, it's because all **AngularFire2** package is moving into **@angular/fire** and this is the recommended way to use from now onwards.