# How to make consistent http calls with observable in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to make chained http calls to api. In first response I get observable, then I use map operator and return this result:

```
     getAreaByKey(key: string): Observable<Area> {
       return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.api}/areas/${key}`).pipe(
        map(result => {
          return {
             'key': result['Key'],
             'name': result['Description'],
             'experts': result['Experts']
          };
       })
     );
  }
```

Then I need to make another http call with parameter **result['Experts']**, which is array with ID's. How can I pass that parameter to next call? I've tried to use SwitchMap, but there is no result. And how to save response data from this calls? because I need to use both in my template.

Comment: You can use `withSwitchMap()` from my observable library which includes the original value. https://github.com/reactgular/observables#withswitchmap

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317494/is-it-good-way-to-call-subscribe-inside-subscribe

The premise of the question is different, but the accepted answer is what you should do

Answer (score 2):

`switchMap` is the right operator to use to chain http calls. Whenever the first observable emits, you can create a second observable using the value emitted.

In your example:

```
getAreaByKey(key: string): Observable<Area> {
   return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.api}/areas/${key}`).pipe(
      map(result => {
         return {
            'key': result['Key'],
            'name': result['Description'],
            'experts': result['Experts']
         };
      }),
      tap(res1 => // save the first response here),
      switchMap(res1 => this.anotherHttpCall(res.experts)),
      tap(res2 => // save the second response here)
   );
}
```

As for saving the data, you can either do this in a tap after each observable as above, or you can use `async | pipe` in the template.

If there is no result, it might be that you are not subscribing to the observable:

```
const obs$ = this.getAreaByKey();  // the observable is defined but the http call has not been made
obs$.subscribe();  // http call is triggered
```

Again, you can do this manually as above or use `async | pipe` in the template.

Comment: If you want to emit results from both http calls you can do `switchMap(res1 => this.anotherHttpCall(res1.experts).pipe(map(res2 => [res1, res2])))`

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://angular.io/guide/observables

```
myObservable.subscribe(
   x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
   err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification')
);
```