# angular access of BehaviorSubject observables in sequence

Tags: angular, observable

The issue is in one angular component, I subscribe to two `Observable` (i.e. `ObsA` and `ObsB`) to get data from two `BehaviorSubject`, in `ObsB.subscribe`, I would like to build new object per each data item from `ObsA.subscribe`, this is when the concurrent nature of `Observable` gets in the way, basically, `ObsB.subscribe` seems to happen earlier than `ObsA.subscribe`, so there is always no `ObsA`'s data to be used to build new objects in `ObsB.subscribe`. Below is the code that illustrate this:

In `MyComponent.ts`

```
ObsAData: any = null;
ObsBData: any = null;

ngOnInit() {
  ObsA.subscribe(dA => {
    this.ObsAData = dA;
  });

  ObsB.subscribe(dB => {
    if (!!dB) {
      //do work
      this.ObsBData = dB;
    } else {
      //no data from ObsB source, hence create new data here based on data from ObsA source
      this.CreateNewBData(this.ObsAData);
    }
  });}
```

The problem is at runtime, `this.ObsAData` is always null when it gets to the `this.CreateNewBData` call. In a sense, creating new `ObsBData` depends on the availability of `ObsAData`, so my natural instinct is to try to somehow "chain" these subscriptions such that the `ObsB.subscribe` happens after `ObsA.subscribe`, but i am not even sure that's logical as it totally runs against the concurrent nature of `Observable`. Any suggestions how to do this effectively? that is to ensure `this.CreatenewBData` always have non-null `this.ObsAData` as its argument **AFTER** `this.ObsAData` indeed is set to non-null data from `this.ObsA` source.

Comment: Consider using `forkJoin` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317592/3503019

Answer (score 0):

My preferred route is to use `combineLatest` in these situations.

```
// RxJS v6+
import { timer, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

const timerOne$ = timer(1000, 4000);
const timerTwo$ = timer(2000, 4000);
const timerThree$ = timer(3000, 4000);

combineLatest(
  timerOne$,
  timerTwo$,
  timerThree$,
  // combineLatest also takes an optional projection function
  (one, two, three) => {
    return `Timer One (Proj) Latest: ${one}, 
              Timer Two (Proj) Latest: ${two}, 
              Timer Three (Proj) Latest: ${three}`;
  }
).subscribe(console.log);
```

( [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-prtbvd?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) )

Notice that timerTwo and timerThree are undefined for the first call. So what you can do is now wrap your logic in a check:

```
// RxJS v6+
import { timer, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

const timerOne$ = timer(1000, 4000);
const timerTwo$ = timer(2000, 4000);
const timerThree$ = timer(3000, 4000);

combineLatest(
  timerOne$,
  timerTwo$,
  timerThree$,
  // combineLatest also takes an optional projection function
  (one, two, three) => {
    if (!!one && !!two && !!three) {
        return `Timer One (Proj) Latest: ${one}, 
              Timer Two (Proj) Latest: ${two}, 
              Timer Three (Proj) Latest: ${three}`;
    }
  }
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: This would never go inside else block of second subscription(OP's code).

Comment: I like the idea, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Here's the work around for this.** You will need to import `first` pipe for this.

When `A` sets `ObsAData` it will set a flag which is subscribed by `B` so that `B` knows whether `ObsAData` value is set? or get informed when value is set to call the `CreateNewBData` function.

```js
    ObsAData: any = null;
    ObsBData: any = null;
    ADataSet$ = new BehaviourSubject<boolean>(false);
    
    ngOnInit() {
      ObsA.subscribe(dA => {
        this.ObsAData = dA;
        if (!this.AdataSet$.value) {
          this.AdataSet$.next(true) // set value so that second subscription would get noticed
        }
      });
    
      ObsB.subscribe(dB => {
        if (!!dB) {
          //do work
          this.ObsBData = dB;
        } else {
          if (!this.ObsAData) {
            this.ADataSet$.pipe(first(r => !!r)).subscribe(e => { // will execute once only when data received
              this.AdataSet$.next(false); // reset the flag
              this.CreateNewBData(this.ObsAData);
            })
          } else {
            this.CreateNewBData(this.ObsAData);
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing you don't ever want to do with async programming. This becomes an uncontrollable mess.

Comment: @IngoBürk I dont think there's anything uncontrollable here. I'd prefer this instead of a non-functioning code. If yuo could suggest an answer if you have any better solution?