# is there a Better way rather than to chain subscribe inside a subscribe with an if condition

Tags: rxjs

Is there a better way to re-write this code and avoid chaining of subscriptions ?

Why am I chaining? because I need to the output of `source1$` in child subscriptions
And also I have `if` conditions because I want to call child subscriptions conditionally

PS i checked solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317494/is-it-good-way-to-call-subscribe-inside-subscribe)

Here is the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-q5bhf1?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) and code

```
    import { from } from 'rxjs';

//emit array as a sequence of values
const source1$ = from([1]);
const source2$ = from([2]);
const source3$ = from([3]);

const useCond1 = true; // this is dynamic can be false too
const useCond2 = true; // this is dynamic can be false too

source1$.subscribe(val => {
  if (useCond1) {
    source2$.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('val from source1 in source2', val);
    });
  }

  if (useCond2) {
    source3$.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('val from source1 in source3', val);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it seems that you need **switchMap** or **mergeMap** and **iif**

from rxjx doc:

```
import { fromEvent, iif, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, map, throttleTime, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

const r$ = of(`I'm saying R!!`);
const x$ = of(`X's always win!!`);

fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
  .pipe(
    throttleTime(50),
    filter((move: MouseEvent) => move.clientY < 210),
    map((move: MouseEvent) => move.clientY),
    mergeMap(yCoord => iif(() => yCoord < 110, r$, x$))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way!

RxJS provides many different operators and static functions for combining, filtering, and transforming observables.  When you use what the library provides, you do not need to have nested subscriptions.

In general, I find it simpler to not do any logic at all inside the subscribe, but rather design observables that emit the exact data that is needed.

A simplistic example could look like this:

```js
someValue$ = source1$.pipe(
  switchMap(val1 => useCond1 ? source2$ : of(val1))
);

someValue$.subscribe();
```

[`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) will subscribe to an "inner observable" whenever it receives an emission.  The logic above says to either return the value emitted from `source1$` (`val1`) or return whatever `source2$` emits depending on the value of `useCond1`.

So `source2$` will only get subscribed to when `useCond1` is true;

Note: the function inside `switchMap` should return an observable (*because switchMap subscribes to it*), so [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) was used to turn the emitted value into an observable.

---

In your case, let's assume you want to emit some calculated value, based possibly on the other two sources.

We can use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) to create a single observable based on 3 different sources.  Since you only want to optionally call `source2$` and `source3$`, we can define the sources based on your conditions.  We can then use [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) to transform the array of values from the 3 sources, into the desired output:

```js
someValue$ = source1$.pipe(
  switchMap(val1 => {
    const s1$ = of(val1);
    const s2$ = useCond1 ? source2$ : of('default val2');
    const s3$ = useCond2 ? source3$ : of('default val3');

    return combineLatest([s1$, s2$, s3$]);
  }),
  map(([val1, val2, val3]) => {
    return ... // your logic to return desired value
  })
);
```

`combineLatest` will emit an array containing the latest emissions from each source whenever any source emits.  This means `someValue$` will emit the latest calculated value whenever any of the sources change.