# How do I chain Angular observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

My component needs to check whether some app preferences are set before API requests are made. Right now I have set it up like this, where I keep my component's data updated on a timer of 2 minutes:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = timer(0, 120 * 1000).subscribe(() => {
        this.shopService.getPreferencesAsObservable().subscribe(preferences => {
            if(preferences) {
                this.getInitialPendingSlotsOrders();
                this.getInitialPendingNoSlotsOrders();
            }
        });
    });
}

getInitialPendingSlotsOrders(){
    this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=PENDING&only_slots=true").subscribe(orders=> {
        /* do stuff with orders */
        /* it can happen that I need to get another page of data */
        if(orders.next_page){
            this.getNextSlotsSetOfPendingOrders();
        }
    });
}

getInitialPendingNoSlotsOrders(){
    this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=PENDING").subscribe(orders=> {
        /* do stuff with orders */
        /* it can happen that I need to get another page of data */
        if(orders.next_page){
            this.getNextNoSlotsSetOfPendingOrders();
        }
    });
}

getNextSlotsSetOfPendingOrders() { 
    this.apiService.fetchNextSetOfOrders(this.nextSlotsUrl).subscribe(nextSetOfOrders => {
        /* do stuff with next set of orders */
    })
}

getNextNoSlotsSetOfPendingOrders() { 
    this.apiService.fetchNextSetOfOrders(this.nextNoSlotsUrl).subscribe(nextSetOfOrders => {
        /* do stuff with next set of orders */
    })
}
```

I thought that this would work but I have reached a scenario where I see that some extra API calls are being made. I know this has something to do with chaining observables. What can I do to clean this up?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have multiple nested subscriptions. They lead to multiple open subscriptions which may never be closed. Instead you'd need to use various RxJS operators available to restrict it to a single subscription.

And seeing you need to trigger two requests in parallel, you could also use RxJS `forkJoin` function.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921) for a quick run down.

In short

- `switchMap` operator to map from one observable to another
- `filter` operator to continue the operator chain based on a condition
- `forkJoin` to combine and trigger multiple observables in parallel

Try the following

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subscription = timer(0, 120 * 1000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.shopService.getPreferencesAsObservable()),
    filter(preferences => !!preferences) // emit only if `preferences` is defined and truthy
    switchMap(() => 
      forkJoin({
        slots: getInitialPendingOrders(true),
        noSlots: getInitialPendingOrders(false)
      })
    )
  ).subscribe({
    next: ({ slots, noSlots }) => {
      // do stuff with orders from `slots` and `noSlots` responses
    },
    error: (error: any) => {
      // handle error
    }
  });
}

getInitialPendingOrders(slots: boolean): Observable<any> {
  return this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=PENDING" + slots ? "&only_slots=true" : '');
}
```

#### Update

As a rule of thumb, you should return the observable and subscribe only where it's response is required. In your case you could pipe in a `switchMap` to each argument of the `forkJoin` and return an observable conditionally. When you do not wish to return anything return RxJS constand `EMPTY` to emit results from the `forkJoin`. Note that `forkJoin` would only emit when all it's source observables complete.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subscription = timer(0, 120 * 1000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.shopService.getPreferencesAsObservable()),
    filter(preferences => !!preferences) // emit only if `preferences` is defined and truthy
    switchMap(() => 
      forkJoin({
        slots: getInitialPendingOrders(true).pipe(
          switchMap((orders: any) => {
            /* do stuff with orders */
            return orders.next_page ? this.getNextSlotsSetOfPendingOrders() : EMPTY;
          })
        ),
        noSlots: getInitialPendingOrders(false).pipe(
          switchMap((orders: any) => {
            /* do stuff with orders */
            return orders.next_page ? this.getNextNoSlotsSetOfPendingOrders() : EMPTY;
          })
        )
      })
    )
  ).subscribe({
    next: ({ slots, noSlots }) => {
      // do stuff with next set of orders from `slots` and `noSlots`
    },
    error: (error: any) => {
      // handle error
    }
  });
}

getInitialPendingOrders(slots: boolean): Observable<any> {
  return this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=PENDING" + !!slots ? "&only_slots=true" : '');
}

getNextSlotsSetOfPendingOrders(): Observable<any> { 
  return this.apiService.fetchNextSetOfOrders(this.nextSlotsUrl);
}

getNextNoSlotsSetOfPendingOrders(): Observable<any> { 
  return this.apiService.fetchNextSetOfOrders(this.nextNoSlotsUrl);
}
```

Comment: This seems exactly what I want! However, I forgot to add in the question that I have another possible layer of subscriptions (updated now)... Could you take a look and maybe update your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @ManuelBrás: Is everything called correctly? The function `getNextSlotsSetOfPendingOrders()` is never seem to be called.

Comment: My mistake! Updated the question now.

Comment: Awesome, I'm about to test this! Btw, if I wanted to initialize some component fields with some of the preferences I receive, where would I do this? Maybe a `tap()` into the preferences after the `filter()`?

Comment: @ManuelBrás: Yes you could pipe in a `tap` operator like `tap(preferences => this.someField = preferences),`. Either before or after the `filter` operator depends on your requirement. If you need all the preferences it could be before the filter. If you need `preferences` only passing a condition, it could be after the `filter` operator.

Comment: Awesome stuff, thank you. I marked your answer as correct in the meantime. Just one last thing: I wanted to be straight to the point in my question so I didn't mention that inside `getNextSlotsSetOfPendingOrders()`  and `getNextNoSlotsSetOfPendingOrders()` it could also happen that I need to get another page of orders, therefore the method would be calling itself with the next page url. Would your solution still apply?

Comment: @ManuelBrás: Yes if you need to trigger another observable within the `getNextSlotsSetOfPendingOrders()` (and it's counterpart), you could do `getNextSlotsSetOfPendingOrders().pipe(switchMap(orders => /* return observable */))` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, never call `subscribe` inside `subscribe` (there are exceptions of course).

I'd recommend you read [Is it good way to call subscribe inside subscribe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317494/is-it-good-way-to-call-subscribe-inside-subscribe) and have a look to the different operators (`forkJoin`, `mergeMap`, ...) RxJs offers to combine observables sequentially, in parallel... depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look. As an Angular amateur I've been struggling getting started with RxJs. Do you have a reference on any tutorial or course specific to RxJs so I can learn it in depth?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty open ended question as there are a lot of ways to chain observables.  [Combination operators on Learn RxJs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination) is a great place to look up all of the different options.

After using rxjs for a while I've started getting into the habit of separating complex processes into const variables or readonly properties, and then having a separate observable that chains them together as kind.  I find it makes things easier to maintain as a class grows. Plus, a lot of times a method was unnecessary as it was just setting up the same stream - execution only occurs when subscribing.

In the example below, after each timer execution the stream switches flow to the *getPreferencesAsObservable()* method which presumably returns an observable that emits once. After the emission, *filer()* is used only when valid preferences are returned.  Finally *forkJoin()* is used to combine the last results from the two observables that get shop orders.

At one point I chose to use *concatMap* and at another *switchMap*.  The former was chosen so that no emissions got skipped in case one emission was true and the subsequent was false.  With *concatMap* the following observables would get executed, but with *switchMap* if the previous emission did not complete then it would get terminated.  Really the choice is up to you based upon the behavior you desire.

```
readonly noSlotsProcess$ = 
  this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=PENDING").pipe(
    tap((x) => /* do stuff */)
  );
readonly slotsProcess$ = 
  this.apiService.fetchShopOrders("status=PENDING&only_slots=true").pipe(
    tap((x) => /* do stuff */)
  );
readonly refresh$ = timer(0, 120 * 1000).pipe(
  concatMap(() => this.shopService.getPreferencesAsObservable()),
  filter((preferences => !!preferences),
  switchMap(() => { forkJoin( noSlots: this.noSlotsProcess$, slots: this.slotsProcess$ }))
);
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.refresh$.subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Even though @MichaelD's answer is working for me, this solution is very clean. I can defnitely take something from it as well, so thank you for taking the time!