# Unexpected token ')' on api subscribtion

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, api, rxjs

I have this API call in an angular application

```
  async upload(file: FileToUpload) { // this is where the error occurs
    file.id = UUID.UUID();

    this.delegates.fileManager.uploadFile(file).subscribe({
      next: async () => {
        this.files = await (await this.delegates.fileManager.getFilesAsync()).files;
        console.log(this.files);
      }
    });
  }
```

the function should upload the file and refresh the file listing with an another api call. This aproach works on the delete function

```
async deleteFile(file: FileToUpload) {
    this.delegates.fileManager.deleteFileById(file.id).subscribe({
      next: async () => {
        this.files = await (await this.delegates.fileManager.getFilesAsync()).files;
      }
    })
  }
```

and while the uploading works, the list doesn't refresh instantly as I have to refresh the page to see the new item. It throws `ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'` even if the `this.files = await (await this.delegates.fileManager.getFilesAsync()).files;` is not here.

Comment: Hi! Do you really need the async way? I mean you can use rxjs operator to update the files after upload. Using mergeMap or switchMap. 
Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317734/12442825

Comment: now I did
`await this.delegates.fileManager.uploadFileAsync(file).finally(async () => {
      this.files = await (await this.delegates.fileManager.getFilesAsync()).files;
});`
and works but throws the same error... strange

Comment: with mergeMap it does have the original symptoms... the file gets uploaded but the list stays the same

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I like the mismatch of `subscribe` and `await`, I would try either all `subscribe` or all `async/await`:

```
upload(file: FileToUpload) { // this is where the error occurs
    file.id = UUID.UUID();
    this.delegates.fileManager.uploadFile(file).subscribe({
      next:() => {
        this.delegates.fileManager.getFilesAsync().subscribe({
           next: (results) => {
              this.files = results.files;
           } 
        })
      }
    });
  }
```