# The right way to catch error and show error message

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am making request to the server and want to show translated error message in case of failure.

I read that passing anonymous `error` function to `subscribe` is [deprecated](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments).

I come up with this code:

```js
this.myService.editSendReport(params)
.pipe(catchError(() => this.translateService.get('settings.report.error')))
.subscribe((res: MyResponce) => {
            // In case of error, we show snack bar with error message.
            if (typeof res === 'string' || res instanceof String) {
                this.snackBar.open(String(res), undefined, {
                    duration: 3000
                });
                return;
            }

            // Success logic
            ...
        });
```

But still I find this code kind of weird, because now we must handle showing error message in `subscribe` in `next` callback. What is the best approach of showing error message now?

`this.translateService.get('settings.report.error')` is also `Observable`. So if I put inside of `error` of `Observer`. I will need to `subscribe` inside of `subscribe`, which is [considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317494/is-it-good-to-call-subscribe-inside-subscribe) an anti-pattern too.

Comment: The linked article shows you how to do it, in the final example - you pass an observer object, instead of two separate callback functions.

Comment: Then it's up to you how you want to represent it. I'd consider the translated error message to _still_ be a failing observable state, so throwError. But that's a different question to the deprecated subscriber interface (as how to handle that error, as covered in the linked docs, is entirely separate to whether or not you consider it one). But "best" is going to be a matter of opinion without objective criteria.

Comment: Have you ever used ErrorInterceptors before?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in an object specifying the `next` and `error` callbacks.

```js
this.myService.editSendReport(params)
  .pipe(catchError(() => this.translateService.get('settings.report.error')))
  .subscribe({
    next: (res: MyResponce) => {
      // handle success
    },
    error: (error: ErrorType) => {
      if (typeof res === 'string' || res instanceof String) {
        this.snackBar.open(String(res), undefined, {
          duration: 3000
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

But given that the `this.translateService.get('settings.report.error')` call corresponds to an observable, I expect the emissions to nevertheless trigger `next` and not the `error` callback.

<strike>In this case, I'd say it's better to forgo the `error` callback and perform the action as a side-effect using the `tap` operator.</strike>

<strike>```typescript
this.myService.editSendReport(params)
  .pipe(
    catchError(() => 
      this.translateService.get('settings.report.error').pipe(
        tap((value) => {
          this.snackBar.open(String(value), undefined, { duration: 3000 });
        })
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (res: MyResponce) => {
      // handle success
    }
  });
```</strike>

**Edit:** The above solution wouldn't work as intended as the `next` callback would be triggered regardless.

Possible solutions that I could think of immediately:

1. Continue using the current implementation: only the `next` callback.
2. Pipe in `switchMap` + `throwError` to the inner observable from `catchError` **with** the `error` callback. And handle the error in `error` callback.
3. Pipe in `switchMap` + `return EMPTY` to the inner observable from `catchError` **without** the `error` callback. And handle the error within the `switchMap` callback.

Comment: Yes, that's a problem, that it triggers `next` and not `error` callback. It would be nice, if we somehow could trigger `error` callback in this case.

Comment: @̶A̶n̶n̶a̶M̶e̶l̶a̶s̶h̶k̶i̶n̶a̶:̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶_̶u̶g̶l̶y̶_̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶`̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶M̶a̶p̶`̶ ̶+̶ ̶`̶t̶h̶r̶o̶w̶E̶r̶r̶o̶r̶`̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶e̶m̶i̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶.̶ ̶B̶u̶t̶ ̶I̶M̶O̶,̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶e̶r̶f̶o̶r̶m̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶o̶p̶e̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶n̶a̶c̶k̶-̶b̶a̶r̶,̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶`̶t̶a̶p̶`̶ ̶o̶p̶e̶r̶a̶t̶o̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶e̶.̶

Comment: Sorry just noticed that the `next` callback would be triggered regardless. You might have to either replace the `tap` with `switchMap` + `return EMPTY` **without** the `error` callback. Or `switchMap` + `throwError` **with** the `error` callback.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle errors is to use [RxJS throwError](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError) like this.

```
this.http
  .get('www.blah.com/api/v1/fake')
  .pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      //Handle the error however you like
      alert(err.message);
      return throwError(() => err);
    })
  )
  .subscribe((resp) => {
    alert('I never get called!');
  });
```

[This is described in this guide here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/) - scroll to "The Catch and Rethrow Strategy". Note that the block in `subscribe` won't get called in this case. I think it's also important to be aware that any error handling you've implemented in HTTP Interceptors will be executed *before* the error handling shown here.

[Here's a stackblitz demonstrating everything](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gkzfd?file=src%2Fmain.ts)