# @angular/fire AngularFireStorage getDownloadUrl()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am trying to use the new @angular/fire 5.1.0
to view an image uploaded to firebase using AngularFireStorage.
I used to be able to make use of `task.downloadURL()` in angularfire2

"correct me if I'm wrong but now I have to use `afStorage.getDownloadURL()`
Please can you kindly assist me with setting imageUrl correctly.

```
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireStorageReference, AngularFireUploadTask } from '@angular/fire/storage'
....
        downloadURL: Observable<string>; 
        imageUrl: string;
....

async onGetFromGallery(){
  try{ ....
    const imageData = await this.camera.getPicture(options);
    const image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    const user = this.authenticatorService.getUser();
    this.ref = this.afStorage.ref(user.uid + '/images/categories/'+id);
    this.task = this.ref.putString(image, 'data_url');

    //--- Previously:angularfire2:
    // this.downloadURL = this.ref.getDownloadURL();
    // this.downloadURL.subscribe(url=> this.imageUrl=url);
    //--- now replaced by this.ref.getDownloadURL()...

    //My Attempt - unable to getDownloadUrl?
    this.task
    .snapshotChanges().toPromise().then(_ =>
       {
        this.ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise().then(res => {
          console.log('URL: ', res);
          this.imageUrl = res;
        });
      })

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    this.errorMessage = JSON.stringify(e);
  }
}
```

view excerpt:

```
<img [src]="imageUrl"  style="width:100%;">
```

package.json excerpt:

> "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11", 
>   "@angular/fire": "^5.1.0", 
>   "firebase": "^5.5.9", 
>   "cordova-android": "~7.0.0",

Thank you.

Comment: According to https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#downloading-files you should only need `this.imageUrl = ref.getDownloadURL()`.

Comment: Please check [https://stackoverflow.com/a/57267424/11127383](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57267424/11127383) for an example how it works at this point of time.

Answer (score 4):

There are some other minor structure changes in the code too, not just renaming the method.

Check out [the example code in the official AngularFire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#monitoring-upload-percentage) under the section titled "*Monitoring upload percentage*". Specifically, the example upload function they include:

```
uploadFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = 'name-your-file-path-here';
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

    // observe percentage changes
    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();

    // get notified when the download URL is available
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
     )
    .subscribe()
}
```

and even more specifically, this part of that function, the listener....

```
// get notified when the download URL is available
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.imageUrl = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
 )
.subscribe()
```

It will fire when the upload has finalized and populate the `this.downloadURL` variable with the URL. You've already defined the `fileRef`, in your code it's just `ref`, so the following *should* work, untested though:

```
    // get notified when the download URL is available
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => this.downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL() )
     )
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Just one last thing. I get the following error on testing:
[ts] Cannot find name 'finalize'. [2304].
Am I missing an import or something?

Comment: Sounds like it, you'll need `import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';` at the top of that component

Comment: Hi @JeremyW. Please can you kindly assist with follow up question? Thanks ;-)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853189/angularfire-storage-task-observable-never-completes