# AngularFire storage task observable never completes

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire5

I am uploading a camera gallery image to firebase successfully, however I am unable to getDownloadURL() as the AngularFire storage task observable never completes.

I have consulted the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md)  following the 'Monitoring upload percentage' - Example Usage [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage)

Please can you kindly advise what I am doing wrong or recommend an alternative approach. Thanks.

```
async onCamera(){
      try{
          const options: CameraOptions = {
          quality: 100,
          targetHeight:500,
          targetWidth:500,
          allowEdit: true,
          correctOrientation: true,
          sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
          destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
        }
        const imageData = await this.camera.getPicture(options);
        const image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
        const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
        const user = this.authenticatorService.getUser();
        const fileRef = this.afStorage.ref(user.uid + '/images/categories/'+id);
        const task = fileRef.putString(image, 'data_url');
        console.log('Done! - I can see this comment successfully logged to the terminal');
        //---------------------------------
        // But this Observable never completes?....
        //---------------------------------
        task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
          finalize(() => {
            console.log('Sequence complete'); // Execute when the observable completes: never logged
            this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
            this.downloadURL.subscribe(url=> this.imageUrl=url);
            console.log('My ImageUrl' + this.imageUrl); // Never logged to terminal?
          }));

        console.log('Finished! - I can see this comment successfully logged to the terminal');
      } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
        this.errorMessage = JSON.stringify(e);
        console.log(this.errorMessage);
      }
    }
```

Relevant Imports

```
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireStorageReference, AngularFireUploadTask } from '@angular/fire/storage';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Camera, CameraOptions} from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
    import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Ionic Native 5 Reference:
https://blog.ionicframework.com/help-test-ionic-native-5/

Relevant Dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.0",
    ....
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.0.0-beta.22",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0-beta.22",
    ...
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "~4.0.3",
    ...
    "firebase": "^5.5.9",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "cordova-android": "~7.1.4"
  },
```

Comment: Are you sure console.log('My ImageUrl' + this.imageUrl); // Never logged to terminal? is not at all executing or imageUrl is empty?

Comment: Yes I am sure as console.log('Sequence complete') inside the finalize block doesn't get logged either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look like you're 99.9% of the way there, nice job on this one! And thanks for providing the links to the docs. I think the reason that the `finalize()` is never firing is because you aren't subscribing to the `.snapshotChanges()`. Without `.subscribe()` your code won't actually listen to the changes fired off by `task.snapshotChanges()`.

In the [example you found](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage), notice that there is a `.subscribe()` stuck on after the `.pipe()`:

```
// get notified when the download URL is available
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
)
.subscribe()
```

So your code should be:

```
//---------------------------------
// But this Observable never completes?....
//---------------------------------
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
        this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
        console.log('My ImageUrl' + this.downloadURL);
    })
).subscribe();
```